# What's the meaning of "legit" in this sentence?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, idioms, slang, african-american-vernacular-english

I've playing a game called GTA san andreas and at the beginning there's a specific part of the first scene that the police ask to character if he's doing something wrong

basically the police says:

> So what else you got shakin', carl?

and then the character says:

> Nothing, I live in liberty city now, I'm clean, **legit**.

my doubt is about the word clean here, i'm discussing about this with some people and they say that this word means something like "**it's true**" but in some translation of the game, the translators translated this to "**someone that is correct, that follows the law**".

when i've discussing with my people here's the meaning they show me in the urban dictionary:

> Legit:
>
> Real. Meaning: Not Fake or Real(Cool).
>
> a. "I swear this watch is legit ......... O.K fine, you can have it
> for $15." b. "That new speaker setup he's got is fully legit and
> shit."

font: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=legit

link of the video that contains the quote:

Link: https://youtu.be/VXyHvYKM67k

timestamp: 1:53

Comment: "Legit" is an abbreviation for "legitimate".  But there a dozen or so different meanings of "legitimate".

Comment: You say "my doubt is about the word clean here," but it seems like your doubt is actually about the word "legit," right?

Comment: The punctuation is non-standard so deciding on the intended meaning becomes even more difficult. But you're right that 'legit' doesn't need to modify a NP (here 'I'). [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/legit) has: **legit** [adverb] US informal: used to mean 'actually' ['honest/ly', 'really'] when you want to say that you think something is very surprising or difficult to believe:
_He was legit driving the car with all the doors open._ But it could also be the abbreviated adjective here ('law-abiding'). There's ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

*Legit* is an adverb here, meaning *really* or *truly*:

> *Nothing, I live in liberty city now, I’m clean, **legit**!*
> *Nothing, I live in liberty city now, I’m clean, **really**!*

See [Merriam-Webster — *legit*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legit):

> **legit** *adverb*
>  slang : REALLY, ACTUALLY  → used for emphasis

Part of your confusion may lie in the fact that *legit* can also be used as an adjective (meaning *real*):

> *I swear this watch is **legit**!*
> *I swear this watch is **real**!*

*Legit* can be an adverb meaning *really* or an adjective meaning *real* — depending on how it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, while legit can mean cool or real, in this case, the speaker means that he is now a law-abiding citizen.

It is legit the legit definition of "legit."

> Legitimate
>
> -adj
>
> 1. Lawfully correct, legal.
>
> ...
>
> also see legit
>
> https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Legitimate

Comment: As an aside, the "clean" part of his statement means that he isn't doing drugs anymore, so my guess would be he used to be a user, possibly a small-time dealer as well, but he neither does nor deals drugs anymore. https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clean